# SSH to Elastic Beanstalk instance as ROOT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using SSH for an Elastic Beanstalk instance has become as easy as using `eb ssh`.
But now I need root access to an environment file and I just can't figure out how I can access the instance as root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you get into the instance using `eb ssh`, then you can become `root` user simply by executing:

```
sudo su -
```